# Concise way to get the intersection of two lists using complex equality comparison?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-3.0

I have two lists of a custom object, and I'd like to get their intersection, but I want a *slightly* complicated method of determining equality.

Simplified example:

```
public class MyClass {
   public string Property1 { get; set; }
   public string Property2 { get; set; }
   public string Property3 { get; set; }
}
```

and I'd like to get the intersection of two `List<MyClass>` where MyClass a & b are considered equal if `a.Property1 == b.Property1 && (a.Property2 == b.Property2 || a.Property3 == b.Property3)`. More specifically, I would like a *concise* way to get their intersection.

[IEnumerable.Intersect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) requires me to go write an extra class just to handle the comparison, since it won't take a lambda.

I'm admittedly new to LINQ syntax, but I couldn't figure out how to write a more complicated `join ... on ... equals ...` clause to handle the property comparison described above.

Should I be doing something more like `list1.Where(a => list2.Select("Property1 = " + a.Property1 + "...").Count == 1)`?

Comment: You want `DistinctBy()` from MoreLINQ.

Comment: @SLaks Looks good, but I think I'd have trouble convincing my boss to add an open source library, especially a LINQ extension library since he never uses LINQ.

Comment: @SLaks, I've been looking for that, well for a long time! If I didn't learn anything today; you got me on that one friend!

Answer (score 0):

So, you want a complex join relation. The easiest way is to do a full join, then filter the interesting items

```
var results = from left in sequence1
              from right in sequence2 // This is a cross join
              where (left.Property1 == right.Property1) &&
                    (left.Property2 == right.Property2 || left.Property3 == right.Property3)
              select new { left, right };
```

In this specific case, however, you are actually doing additional filtering on a regular inner join:

```
var results = from left in sequence1
              join right in sequence2 on left.Property1 equals right.Property1
              where (left.Property2 == right.Property2 || left.Property3 == right.Property3)
              select new { left, right };
```